# if-and-else condition not met but header still executes

Tags: php, header

I am having a strange problem where I am able to execute the header functions in if-and-else statements that should be unreachable, for example...

```
//www.example.com/search/title/harry+potter


$path = explode("/", trim(trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),"/"));

if(!$path){
    //if array is empty go back to index
    header("Location: /");
}

else if(!$path[1] || !$path[2]){
    //if neither index 1 or 2 are set go back to index
    header("Location: /");
}
```

This code should not redirect the user given that none of the if-and-else statements are met, but for some reason it seems to redirect the user from the second else-if statement.

If I replace the `header()` function with `echo "test"` nothing happens.

I'm baffled, what could the problem be?

Comment: What do you see if you replace the `header` calls with `var_dump($path)`?

Comment: @Barmar nothing happens

Comment: If you don't see anything, then you're not getting into the `else if`. The redirect is happening somewhere else.

Comment: OK thanks, the problem is sorted now

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend you a headache solver? You could create this short and seo friendly urls using [URL Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) and make your life much easier.  [Check this out](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your assumptions. For example, if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` returns the string `/` then the explode function will return an array with two elements, both containing an empty string.

If your URI has the string `//` at the beginning then `$path[0]` and `$path[1]` will be both empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with how you have your if conditions are set up. Try something like this:

```
<?php
//www.example.com/search/title/harry+potter

$URI = "/search/title/harry+potter";

// Placeholder for $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    $path = explode("/", trim( trim( $URI ), "/") );
// Test $path as empty array
    //$path = array();
// Test $path as empty string
    //$path = "";

var_dump($path);

if( !isset($path) || empty($path) ){
    //if array is empty go back to index
    echo "Is empty $ path";    
    // header("Location: /");

} else if ( strlen($path[1]) < 1 && strlen($path[2]) < 1) {
    //if neither index 1 or 2 are set go back to index
    echo "$ path[1] and $ path[2] are both empty";    
    // header("Location: /");

} else {
    echo "$ path is an array with value in position 1 and/or 2";
}
```

http://codepad.org/fST5A20o